# How to create kotlin.collections.Set from plain JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-js

I'm trying to call from plain JavaScript into a Kotlin module that has been compiled into JavaScript. One of the Kotlin methods inside the module requires a `kotlin.collections.Set` to be passed. How can I create such a set object from a plain JavaScript array? I've looked into the compiled code, and Kotlin makes internal references to methods like `Kotlin.kotlin.collections.setOf_i5x0yv$` but I see no way to call these from outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-to-kotlin-interop.html#representing-kotlin-types-in-javascript) Sets are not represented in Javascript.

Arrays on the other hand are mapped. Therefore a simple function can be written which maps a Javascript Array into a Kotlin Set.

```
@JsName("createSetFromJsArray")
fun <TValue> createSetFromJsArray(array: Array<TValue>) = array.toSet()
```

This function can be used when calling a Kotlin function from Javascript like this:

```
var test = ["a", "b", "c"];
aKotlinFunction(createSetFromJsArray(test));
```

and a Kotlin function implemented like:

```
@JsName("aKotlinFunction")
fun aKotlinFunction(test: Set<String>) {
    console.log("aKotlinFunction called with param ${test.joinToString()}")
}
```